# jq - remove duplicates from arrays

Tags: arrays, json, unique, jq

i want to remove the duplicates from each array in this json:

```json
{
  "abc": [
    "five"
  ],
  "pqr": [
    "one",
    "one",
    "two",
    "two",
    "three",
    "three",
    "four",
    "four"
  ],
  "xyz": [
    "one",
    "one",
    "two",
    "two",
    "four"
  ]
}
```

output I am expecting after removing the duplicates:

```json
{
  "abc": [
    "five"
  ],
  "pqr": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
  ],
  "xyz": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "four"
  ]
}
```

i tried map, uniq, group_by with `jq` but nothing helped

Comment: Try [`unique`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by(path_exp))

Comment: @pmf I tried `unique` but it works only on an array, I want the json structure intact, only duplicate values from array needs to be removed.

Comment: Yes, `unique` works on an array. As you want the arrays to be de-duplicated, this is what you need. Use `|=` to update the arrays from the top level context. Also, I forgot that `unique` automatically sorts the arrays. I have added a full answer below showing how to circumvent the sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`unique`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by(path_exp)) can remove duplicates, but it automatically sorts the arrays, which may or may not be what you want.

```bash
jq '.[] |= unique'
```

```json
{
  "abc": [
    "five"
  ],
  "pqr": [
    "four",
    "one",
    "three",
    "two"
  ],
  "xyz": [
    "four",
    "one",
    "two"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pWSM7hDsM1A)

You can retrieve the original ordering by recreating the array based on [`sort`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sort,sort_by(path_expression)) ing the [`index`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#index(s),rindex(s)) positions of all of its `unique` items:

```bash
jq '.[] |= [.[[index(unique[])] | sort[]]]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MfOuUd8qU_5)

Or circumvent any sorting behaviour by writing your own straightforward de-duplication function:

```bash
jq '.[] |= reduce .[] as $i ([]; . + if index($i) then [] else [$i] end)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/v7KwJ44a8XZ)

In my tests, the latter performed best, with both producing

```json
{
  "abc": [
    "five"
  ],
  "pqr": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
  ],
  "xyz": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "four"
  ]
}
```

Comment: in my case, i am okay in sorting array elements. First option is so simple, I had tried unique but without = sign which was removing the key so posted the question, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sort-free alternative for obtaining the distinct items in an array (or stream) while retaining the order of first occurrence.

It uses a filter that is a tiny bit more complex than it would otherwise be, for the sake of complete genericity:

```
# generate a stream of the distinct items in `stream`
# in order of first occurrence, without sorting
def uniques(stream):
  foreach stream as $s ({};
     ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tostring) end) as $y
     | if .[$t][$y] then .emit = false else .emit = true | (.item = $s) | (.[$t][$y] = true) end;
     if .emit then .item else empty end );
```

Now it's just a matter of applying this filter to your JSON.  One possibility would be:

```
 map_values([uniques(.[])])
```